# Subsetting a dataset

Tags: r, subset

I have the following data (I am just giving the first 10 rows). I want to get the number of times the value of `TRBV == TRBV20-1` when `subject == 19` and `stim == 1100-2`.

I tried the following code to subst the data

```
new_data <- my_data[my_data (my_data$subject == 'HAT-19' & my_data$stim == '1100-2'), TRBV == 'TRBV20-1')]
```

It gives me error.

Could you please help?

```
subject    stim       TRBV    
   <chr>   <chr>      <chr>   
 1 HAT-19  (2) 1100-2 TRBV20-1
 2 HAT-19  (2) 1100-2 TRBV7-6 
 3 HAT-19  (2) 1100-2 TRBV6-4 
 4 HAT-19  (2) 1100-2 TRBV6-4 
 5 HAT-1001 (3) BSV18  TRBV3-1 
 6 HAT-1  (3) BSV18  TRBV6-4 
 7 HAT-10 (2) 1100-2 TRBV3-1 
 8 HAT-12  (2) 1100-2 TRBV6-4 
 9 HAT-38  (2) 1100-2 TRBV6-1 
10 HAT-15 (2) 1100-2 TRBV6-1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use dplyr and an ifelse statement:

```
my_data %>%
  mutate(numoftimes = ifelse(subject == 'HAT-19' & stim == '1100-2' & TRBV == 'TRBV20-1',1,0)) %>% 
  sum(numoftimes)
```